# Java with a for loop with in for loop

Tags: java

I am not sure why this isn't working to the questionhave to use a one dimensional integer array to count the number of times each possible sum appears in 36000 rolls.

However my problem is I that keep getting all 0.0 instead of something like 1200000 or 700000.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class StockSim {



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double data[] = new double[10];



        System.out.println(percentGen());

        double percent;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                percent = percentGen();
                data[i] = data[i] + (data[i] * percent);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(data[i]);
        }

    }

    public static double percentGen() {
        Random rand = new Random();


        return randomNum;

    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't what a percent is. You're multiplying the value by a random number from -30 to 30, not increasing or decreasing it by up to 30%.

Comment: @KSFT data[i] = data[i] + (data[i] * percent); wouldn't this suffice?

Comment: No, it would not. Multiplying a number by 30 is not the same as increasing it by 30%.

Comment: to increase something by 30% multiply it by 1.3

Comment: any solutions? like data[i] * (1+percent)  would this help

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple fix, you just forgot to get the actual percentage by dividing the random percentage by one hundred. Substitute your `return randomNum` by `return randomNum/100`.

Besides that, I tested your code and it should be working just fine.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to move the instantiation of the Random class outside the loop or provide a random seed  otherwise the results are not random. For example you could instantiate the Random class and pass it as an argument to percentGen

```
Random rand= new Random()
System.out.println(percentGen(rand));
```